# JOIN two columns in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

What should I do if I want every time I fill out column C, to all data from B6 to C14 would appear on the notes?

[image]

Comment: Please add an example of what you mean to enter, and you mean to get as a result of it.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(CHAR(10), B6:B14&" "&C6:C14))
```

[image]